# Microsoft Excel Power Query to Get Access Data , Based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, power-query

I need to export MS Access data to MS Excel by Power query

Here I need to filter ID by cell value A1

This is the query

```
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Database2021.mdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Hours = Source{[Schema="",Item="Hours"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_Hours, each ([ID] = "6734"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

I need to set  from this **6734** Value to CELL **A1**

Is it possible, kindly guide me.

Edit1;

```
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Database2021.mdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Hours = Source{[Schema="",Item="Hours"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_Hours, each ([ID] = "idfilter"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

idFilter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourID"]}[Content]
```

When I enter the suggested line at the last, it will get an error.
Named A1 as YourID

Comment: I think you need to **Name** cell `A1`. Then you can load it into your query. Something like `idFilter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangeName"]}[Content]`

Comment: Token EOF expected error occur in idfilter

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  Works fine here. You'll need to edit your question with sufficient information to enable someone to reproduce your error.

Comment: You have to define `idFilter` before you can use it.

Comment: How to define it

Comment: By having it on a line before the line that refers to it.  Perhaps you should consider doing an internet search for a tutorial in the basics of Power Query and M Code, before getting into this level of progamming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Goto Excel; **Data**> **New Query**> **From Access database**>Goto your Location and select the **File**> Choose your **Table** to Display>Click **Edit**> Apply **Filter** Manually as per your requirement> Click **Load to**> Select your destination in Excel file.

[image: Access to Excel Data Filter by cell value]

Step2: Create New Table for Filter the Value> Name the Table  **EMPDATA** >Goto Data tab > Click **From Table**> Query Editor will shows> Name the Query As **EMPDATA** > remove **Changetype** in Navigation tree> makesure your Filter value **data type**must same> Goto Advance editor> Now precode available

You have to add the line with your code to define it. Also update the *EmpNo* as per your requirement

```
 AndCriteria01 = Record.Field(Source{0},"EmpNo")
in
    AndCriteria01
```

This is our code After update it. Click Load to > Create Connection Only

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="EMPDATA"]}[Content],
    AndCriteria01 = Record.Field(Source{0},"EmpNo")
in
    AndCriteria01
```

[image: NAme the Value]

---

Now Get back to our Main Query

- Auto generated code

```
let
  Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Database2021.mdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Hours = Source{[Schema="",Item="Hours"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_Hours, each ([ID] = "6734"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows
```

Then Add this Line
Before Source

```
ANDCriteria01 = EMPDATA,
```

Also Replace the **"6734"** Direct value to **EMPDATA**

So Our Final code will comes to this format

```
let
    ANDCriteria01 = EMPDATA,
  Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Database2021.mdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
    _Hours = Source{[Schema="",Item="Hours"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_Hours, each ([ID] = EMPDATA))
in
    #"Filtered Rows
```

Now Click load and save. that's it.

make sure , comma must each line and ensure spell for each parameters